# how to fix the photo that doesn't scale correctly in this react component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

[image]

the photo should be positioned to the right and become smaller than the parent element, this is a react component and the photo should be placed responsively.

```
.image {
    position: absolute;
    
    border-radius: 1rem;
      left:0px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

the html of the photo container:

```
  <div className={styles.container}>
       
      <div className={styles.title}>{title}</div>
     
      <div className={styles.about}>{about}</div>
     <img src={image} alt={title} className={styles.image} />
    
    </div>


.container {
  width: auto;
  @include flex(column, center, flex-start);
  padding: 3rem 10rem;
  background: #2697fe;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;}

.image {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  height: auto;
  right:    20vw; 
  max-width: 80%;
  }
```

it gives this result and I need help with the position of the photo again: [image]

the photo in the small size screen(the border is no longer rounded):

[image]

Comment: you will need to add `position: relative` to the parent.

Comment: Yes, it already has position:relative

Comment: Then you will need to give it `right:0` instead of `left:0` also add `height:100%` to the `.image` style class.

Comment: It moves the photo to the right and it looks the same overall

Comment: @maimohamed, Can you post the html related to the image and it's parent as well as the parent css.

Comment: it's a react component not html @g0rb

Comment: @maimohamed, my mistake. Can you post the jsx?

Comment: @g0rb please check the answer again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your HTML document structure is like this:

```
<div className="section1">
    <div className="text">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      </p>
    </div>
    <img className="image" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="img" />
  </div>
```

Using the Position property may not give you an appropriate layout every time in such designs.
You can make use of the CSS [Flex Box](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) to arrange the items inside the "section1" like this:

```
.section1 {
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.image {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  right: 20vw;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

/* rsponsive design --- small screen size */
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .section1 {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .image {
    border-radius: 1rem;
    right: 0;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
}
```

This will give you a layout like this:

[small screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTbmn.png)

[large screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfCnO.png)

hope this answers your question :)

Comment: this is the most precise answer but flexbox justify-content: space-around; doesn't really work for the title and the about divs

Comment: You have to separate the img tag and the rest of the content by putting the rest of the text into a wrapping div like in my answer (className = "text). This will separate the cpmponents inside the parent container into two components, making the problem simpler.

Comment: it works but the border of the photo is not rounded in the small screen size(on my device)

Answer (score 0):

make sure to give the parent div that holds the image a width and height.

Then make sure that the image has a `max-width: 100%` and a `max-height: 100%` Don't work with width and height with images as that can lead to horrible responsive issue's.

Hope this helped, if theres something I can do better to bring more clarity let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more flexbox structure around your HTML/JSX elements to get the image to sit to the right of the text. If you want to have the image sit inline with the text, the flex-box direction should be row (which is the default).

i.e.,

```
// jsx 

  <div className={styles.container}>
    <div className={styles.innerContainer}>
      <div>                           <-- Extra surrounding divs keeps flex children elements grouped correctly.
        <div className={styles.title}>{title}</div>
        <div className={styles.about}>{about}</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src={image} alt={title} className={styles.image} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
// styles

.container {
  width: auto;
  @include flex(column, center, flex-start);
  padding: 3rem 10rem;
  background: #2697fe;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-container {
  display: flex; <-- puts image inline. (direction "row" by default)
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Depending on how much you want the image to sit to the right, you may need to modify the container and inner-container styles.